# Scrape Twitter with Python for Movie list

Tags: python, twitter, scrape

I am using the crowdflower movies dataset and want to scrape twitter for the tweets related to every movie in the dataset.

I am new to python and would appreciate any help. I tried searching for solutions online but I do not understand anything

I have already imported the dataset. It would be best to know how to code for streaming and nonstreaming tweets.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you gather tweets from Twitters API as opposed to scrapping them because it's 10x easier.  I would also recommend using [Tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy), a Python library that makes interacting with Twitters API easy.

[Here's](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-twitterbot-with-python-3-and-the-tweepy-library) a good tutorial I found on how to integrate Tweepy into your project.

PS - remember not to commit your API keys